# Javascript OpenLayers before zoom event listener

Tags: javascript, google-maps, openlayers, zooming

I am trying to set up OpenLayers to not display the vector layer just before a zoom starts and make it reappear after a zoom ends. I have the zoom ends part already established like this:

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map('map_element', { eventListeners: { "zoomend": mapEvent}});

function mapEvent(event) {
    if(event.type == "zoomend") {
        hide_vector_layer();
        }
}
```

But I don't see any kind of event listener for the start of a zoom in the documentation. There is a "movestart" which covers moving, panning, and zoom. Unfortunately, I can't use the "movestart" one, because I don't want the layer to disappear during a pan. You would think there would be a "zoomstart", as there is a "zoomend".

The reason I am trying to do this, is because I don't like how the vector layer zooms at a different rate when using Google Maps as a base layer. It looks wrong, looks like all the features are inaccurate, even though they land in the right place after the zoom is complete.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this purpose you should override moveTo and moveByPx methods of OpenLayers.Map for eliminate movestart event triggering for any actions except zooming.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a easy to add the 'BeforeZoom' event to the OpenLayers . Just add the code below to where you created your map object.

```
map.zoomToProxy = map.zoomTo;
map.zoomTo =  function (zoom,xy){
    //Your Before Zoom Actions

    //If you want zoom to go through call
    map.zoomToProxy(zoom,xy); 
    //else do nothing and map wont zoom
};
```

How this works:

For any kind of zooming activity, OpenLayers API ultimately calls the function called zoomTo. So before overriding it, we copy that function to a new function called 'zoomToProxy'. The we override it and add our conditional zoom logic. If we want the zoom to happen we just call new proxy function :)

Comment: This approach works, but just to be more safe you should replace the line inside the function to map.zoomToProxy.apply(this, arguments); so if they add new arguments to zoomTo they get passed along too.

Comment: Ah I also forgot to mention that the OpenLayers API calls zoomTo before actually performing the zoom, so you can use the code before the first comment to do things as if it was a 'zoomstart' event. You can prevent the zoom from happening for example.

Comment: Right on both counts.Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem that OP had, and I tried to solve it with drnextgis's solution. But unfortunately it didn't completely work:: the `zoomChanged` property in OpenLayers.Map.moveTo evaluates to `true` not only when the zoom level has changed, but also when the map has been resized.

My map was 100% of the user's browser window, so if they resized the window, the event would be triggered. This was undesirable for me, as I only wanted to trigger the event if the zoom level had actually changed. My solution was to create an new event, called "zoomstart", which I inserted at the top of OpenLayers.Map.moveTo. Here's the code:

```
var getZoom = this.getZoom();
if ( !!getZoom && !!zoom && this.isValidZoomLevel(zoom) && getZoom != zoom )
    this.events.triggerEvent("zoomstart", zoom);
```

This code will pass the new zoom level to an event listener that is registered to `zoomstart`, and in my case I determine the map's restrictedExtent and do other stuff based upon the new zoom level.

Peace be with ye.

Answer (score 1):

"movestart" handles "zoomstart". To detect if the zoomstart, try:

```
 map.events.register("movestart",map, function(e) {
        if(e.zoomChanged)
        {
        //zoom start code here
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution of "Shaunak" is worked very well for me.
I want to restrict zooming below 11 so edited his code as

```
if (zoom > 11) {
    map.zoomToProxy(zoom, xy);
}
```

Comment: This should be posted as a *comment* on Shaunak's answer, not as a separate answer.