# How to add on rotation and zoom listener on OpenLayers 6?

Tags: rotation, html-lists, zooming, openlayers, openlayers-6

Im trying to handle Rotation and Zoom interactions. 
Is it possible to create one listener for all interactions created by `DragRotateAndZoom`?

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_interaction_DragRotateAndZoom-DragRotateAndZoom.html

```
...
      interactions: defaultInteractions().extend([
        new DragRotateAndZoom()
      ]),
...
```

Is there any way to use something like

```
    this.map.on('rotate', (e) => {
      console.log(e);
    });
```

OR

```
    this.map.on('zoom', (e) => {
      console.log(e);
    });
```

found an solution for an old version (7 years old!) ->
[Javascript OpenLayers before zoom event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11181542/javascript-openlayers-before-zoom-event-listener?rq=1)

Comment: Use `this.map.getView().on('change:resolution', ...)` and `this.map.getView().on('change:rotation', ...)`
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_View-View.html

Comment: If you want to have the same callback, this also works:
`this.map.getView().on(['change:resolution', 'change:rotation'], (e) => {})`